# The data is not inserting in database using hibernateTemplate class

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate integration and trying to make a simple CRUD application with MYSQL as a backend.

```
Here is my Employee.java 


package com.springhibernate;


public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;
    
    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}

EmployeeDao.java

    package com.springhibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {
    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    // method to save employee
    public void saveEmployee(Employee e) {
        System.out.println(e.getId());
        System.out.println(e.getName());
        System.out.println(e.getSalary());
        template.save(e);
        System.out.println("After template.save method");
    }

    // method to update employee
    public void updateEmployee(Employee e) {
        template.update(e);
    }

    // method to delete employee
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee e) {
        template.delete(e);
    }

    // method to return one employee of given id
    public Employee getById(int id) {
        Employee e = (Employee) template.get(Employee.class, id);
        return e;
    }

    // method to return all employees
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list = template.loadAll(Employee.class);
        template.setCheckWriteOperations(false);
        return list;
    }

}

applicationContext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nupur" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="nupur" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="d" class="com.springhibernate.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>

InsertTest.java

package com.springhibernate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class InsertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

        EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao) factory.getBean("d");

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(164);
        e.setName("varun");
        e.setSalary(50000);

        System.out.println("Before calling dao method");
        dao.saveEmployee(e);
        System.out.println("After calling dao method");
    }

}

Employee.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 3, 2016 1:19:10 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.springhibernate.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="salary" type="float">
            <column name="SALARY" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The console is showing no errors, still the data is not inserted in database, please tell me where I am getting wrong?

I had printed some of the sout statements to check till where the code
is executing and the output is as follows :

> Before calling dao method 164 varun
>
> 50000.0 After template.save method After calling dao method

Comment: does the string "After template.save method" gets printed in your console?

Comment: For starters, use an `ApplicationContext` not a `BeanFactory`. Second add a transaction manager, put `@Transactional` on your dao and add `<tx:annotation-driven />` to your configuration. Without trnsactions nothing will be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Add declarative transaction management as below in EmployeeDao.java class.

```
@Transactional
public void saveEmployee(Employee e) {
    System.out.println(e.getId());
    System.out.println(e.getName());
    System.out.println(e.getSalary());
    template.save(e);
    System.out.println("After template.save method");
}
```

In Spring, you should use declarative transaction management, which allows you to avoid opening, committing, closing and flushing. It's all done by Spring automatically.

Comment: I added @Transactional but then also the data is not inserting

Comment: have you added <tx:annotation-driven /> in your configuration file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

<tx:annotation-driven />

Comment: I added tx:annotation-driven but then also none of the effects is been showing in db

Comment: you also need to add transaction manager, here is an example for xml based config http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring_hibernate_integration_example

Comment: I tried to execute your code without transaction management and it is working fine. I used spring 3.2.6 and hibernate 3.2.x versions. I have used org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate and org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean. For more details related to spring declarative transaction management please see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative

Comment: I am not trying to execute code, I am just practising and hence want to know where I am getting wrong???

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet to check with Eclipse but I have some ideas for you:

1. Model classes should have constructors fully, especially if you use @Autowired for DaoImpl classes. Here they are Employee() and Employee(id, name, salary)
2. add @Repository in DaoImpl classes, @Controller in Controller, @Transactional in DaoImpl if use transaction, @Service in Service classes.
   Here you registried , so don't need @Repository

Comment: I added all the things but then also it is not working.. can you please tell me the problem in my code??

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't find problem in your code now. But as a reference for Hibernate, you can use it:  https://github.com/thamluong/test